# Name conflict between msg and srv

Tags: ros, catkin-make, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want publish a message reporting an actuator state change, but I also want to provide a service to allow setting that state. When I tried to create a msg called MyState and srv called MyState, catkin_make gives me a name conflict error. Why can't msg and srv files use the same name? Do they share the same namespace?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232050/name-conflict-between-msg-and-srv/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-04-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No you cannot have a Msg and Srv of the same name in the same package. Messages and Services are identified by both the package they are in and the name. For example, `std_msgs/String` is different from `your_package/String`. You cannot, however, have `std_msgs/Empty.msg` and `std_msgs/Empty.srv`. That's why, for example, we have `std_msgs/Empty` (http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Empty.html) which is a message and a separate package for `std_srvs/Empty` (http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/std_srvs/html/srv/Empty.html) which is a service.

ROS 2 isn't ready yet, but this ambiguity doesn't exist in ROS 2 anymore. Messages and Services will not share a flat namespace.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3